# Val loss behaves strange while using custom training loop in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using a VGG16 model written in `tf2.0` to train on my own datasets. Some BatchNormalization layers were included in the model and the `"training"` argument were set to `True` during training time and `False` during validation time as described in many tutorials.
The train_loss decreased to a certain level during training as expected. 
 However, the val_loss behaves really strange. I checked out the output of the model after training and found out that, if I set the `training` argument to `True`, the output is quite correct, but if I set it to `False`, the result is incorrect at all.
According to the tutorials in tensorflow website, when `training` is set to `False` , the model will normalize its inputs using the mean and variance of its moving statistics learned during training but it doesn't seem so. Am I missing something?

I've provided the trainning and validation code in the below.

```py
def train():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    tdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_img_list[:200], train_label_list[:200]))
    tdataset = tdataset.map(parse_function, 3).shuffle(buffer_size=200).batch(batch_size).repeat(repeat_times)
    vdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_img_list[:100], val_label_list[:100]))
    vdataset = vdataset.map(parse_function, 3).batch(batch_size)

    ### Vgg model
    model = VGG_PR(num_classes=num_label)

    logging.info('Model loaded')

    start_epoch = 0
    latest_ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(ckpt_path))
    if latest_ckpt:
        start_epoch = int(latest_ckpt.split('-')[1].split('.')[0])
        model.load_weights(latest_ckpt)
        logging.info('model resumed from: {}, start at epoch: {}'.format(latest_ckpt, start_epoch))
    else:
        logging.info('training from scratch since weights no there')

    ######## training loop ########
    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    val_loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=initial_lr)
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss') 
    val_loss = tf.metrics.Mean(name='val_loss')
    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_path.format(case_num))

    with writer.as_default():
        for epoch in range(start_epoch, total_epoch):
            print('start training')
            try:
                for batch, data in enumerate(tdataset):
                    images, labels = data
                    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                        pred = model(images, training=True)
                        if len(pred.shape) == 2:
                            pred = tf.reshape(pred,[-1, 1, 1, num_label])
                        loss = loss_object(pred, labels)
                    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
                    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
                    if batch % 20 ==0:
                        logging.info('Epoch: {}, iter: {}, loss:{}'.format(epoch, batch, loss.numpy()))
                    tf.summary.scalar('train_loss', loss.numpy(), step=epoch*1250*repeat_times+batch)      # the tdataset has been repeated 5 times..
                    tf.summary.text('Zernike_coe_pred', tf.as_string(tf.squeeze(pred)), step=epoch*1250*repeat_times+batch)
                    tf.summary.text('Zernike_coe_gt', tf.as_string(tf.squeeze(labels)), step=epoch*1250*repeat_times+batch)

                    writer.flush()
                    train_loss(loss)
                model.save_weights(ckpt_path.format(epoch=epoch))
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                logging.info('interrupted.')
                model.save_weights(ckpt_path.format(epoch=epoch))
                logging.info('model saved into {}'.format(ckpt_path.format(epoch=epoch)))
                exit(0)
            # validation step
            for batch, data in enumerate(vdataset):
                images, labels = data
                val_pred = model(images, training=False)
                if len(val_pred.shape) == 2:
                    val_pred = tf.reshape(val_pred,[-1, 1, 1, num_label])
                v_loss = val_loss_object(val_pred, labels)
                val_loss(v_loss)
            logging.info('Epoch: {}, average train_loss:{}, val_loss: {}'.format(epoch, train_loss.result(), val_loss.result()))
            tf.summary.scalar('val_loss', val_loss.result(), step = epoch)
            writer.flush()
            train_loss.reset_states()
            val_loss.reset_states()
        model.save_weights(ckpt_path.format(epoch=epoch))
```

The train losss reduced to a very small value like the groundtruth label are in the range of [0, 1] and the average train loss can be 0.007, but the val loss is much higher than this. The output of the model tends to be close to 0 if I set `training` to `False`.

**updated on Nov. 6th**:
I have found an interesting thing that if I use `tf.function` to decorate my model in its `call` method, the `val loss` will turn to be correct, but I'm not sure what has happened?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Answer for the benefit of the community.

Issue is resolved, i.e., `val loss` will turn to be correct if `tf.function` is used to decorate the `model` in its `call` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm wondering what you mean by 'here'? (Guess there supposed to be a super link?)